# Configuration Recommendations for a PostgreSQL Installation

Tags: postgresql, configuration, windows-server-2003

I have a Windows Server 2003 machine which I will be using as a Postgres database server, the machine is a Dual Core 3.0Ghz Xeon with 4 GB ECC Memory and 4 x 120GB 10K RPM SAS Drives, all stripped.

I have read that the default Postgres install is configured to run nicely on a 486 with 32MB RAM, and I have read several web pages about configuration optimizations - but was hoping for something more concrete from my Stackoverflow peeps.

Generally, its only going to serve 1 database (**potentially** one or two more) but the catch is that the database has 1 table in particular which is massive (hundreds of millions of records with only a few coloumn).  Presently, with the default configuration, **it's not slow**, but I think it could potentially be even faster.

Can people please give me some guidance and recomendations for configuration settings which *you* would use for a server such as this.

Comment: You're (probably) asking the wrong people here, you should head over to http://serverfault.com/ and ask there and you'll get a much better response.

Comment: I've asked simmilar question in stack overflow before with great success - mainly becasue its one thing to configure a server - and another thing entirely to break configurations which are going to effect client code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- 4*stripped drive was a bad idea — if any of this drives will fail then you'll loose all data, and even SAS drives sometimes fail — with 4 drivers it is 4 times more likely than with 1 drive; you should go for [RAID 1+0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_RAID_levels#RAID_10_.28RAID_1.2B0.29).
- Use the latest version of Postgres, 8.3.7 now; there are many performance improvements in every major version.
- Set `shared_buffers` parameter in `postgresql.conf` to about 1/4 of your memory.
- Set `effective_cache_size` to about 1/2 of your memory.
- Set `checkpoint_segments` to about 32 (checkpoint every 512MB) and `checkpoint_completion_target` to about 0.8.
- Set `default_statistics_target` to about 100.
- Migrate to Enterprise Linux or FreeBSD: Postgres works much better on Unix type systems — Windows support is a recent addition, not very mature.

You can read more on this page: [Tuning Your PostgreSQL Server — PostgreSQL Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server)

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for - thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

My experience suggests that (within limits) the hardware is typically the least important factor in database performance.

Assuming that you have enough memory to keep commonly used data in cache, then your CPU speed may vary 10-50% between a top-of the line machine and a common or garden box.

However, a missing index in an important search, or a poorly written recursive trigger could easily make a difference of 1,000% or 10,000% or more in your response times.

Without knowing exactly your table structure and row counts, I think anybody would suggest that your your hardware looks amply sufficient.  It is only your database structure which will kill you.  :)

UPDATE:

Without knowing the specific queries and your index details, there's not much more we can do.  And in general, even knowing the queries, it's often very difficult to optimize without actually installing and running the queries with realistic data sets.

Given the cost of the server, and the cost of your time, I think you need to invest thirty bucks in a book.  Then install your database with test data, run the queries, and see what runs well and what runs badly.  Fix, rinse, and repeat.

Both of these books are specific to SQL Server and both have high ratings:

[http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Microsoft%C2%AE-SQL-Server-2005/dp/0735621969/ref=sr_1_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621969)

[http://www.amazon.com/Server-Performance-Tuning-Distilled-Second/dp/B001GAQ53E/ref=sr_1_5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001GAQ53E)

Comment: Yeah ther server is a beast, no doubt...again, this question is more about configuration improvements, not specifically about "hardware".  My reasoning for asking at stackoverflow is becasue I am very aware that the settings used to tweak memory caching and query performance are directly tied to max connections and I dont want to change a setting which will make things worse either by limiting the number of database connections, or over-using memory.